# Remove create button inside filamentPHP view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I am currently working on a Laravel project using filamentPHP. However I cannot find a way to delete the create functionality for a specific resource.
Considering there is a resource named Customer, in the view page, I would like to remove the new customer button located at the top of the list. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm using filament v2.16.66 with Laravel 9.19.

What works for me in order to remove create button in certain lists, is adding the following function in eg: `App\Filament\Resources\CustomerResource`

```
    public static function canCreate(): bool
   {
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: Another way I found recently is to comment out the Create method in your ExampleResource/Pages/CreateExample.php class

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it by override canCreate() and return it as false.

```
class Customer
{
   public static $resource = CustomerResource::class;

   protected function canCreate(): bool
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Laravel specific solution is to create a new policy, and override the create() function to return false, like the following:

```
public function create()
{
   return false;
}
```

Note: Do not forget to assign the required model to this new policy in /Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just remove the CreateAction::make() from the List page's getActions(). No need to override methods.

```
protected function getActions(): array
{
    return [
        //  Actions\CreateAction::make(),
    ];
}
```

Based on: https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/discussions/3774#discussioncomment-3516256

Answer (score 0):

With latest Filament 3.x APIs have changed and here is what I would use.

### Option 1

Using List page and commenting out `Actions\CreateAction::make()` only *hides* button but you can still navigate to /create page and create record.

```php
protected function getHeaderActions(): array
    {
        return [
            // Actions\CreateAction::make(),
        ];
    }
```

### Option 2

Using Resource `canCreate()` is safer option as it not only that it will hide button, but it will throw 403 if you try to navigate to /create. Basically much safer approach.

```php
// Add to your Resource class
// Supports Filament 3.10
public static function canCreate(): bool
    {
        return false;
    }
```

### Example of Resource

(partial resource, to give you idea)

```php
class ClientsResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Clients::class;
    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-rectangle-stack';
    // ... the rest of your decplarations

    // Filament 3.x supported with new fresh api
    public static function canCreate(): bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    // ...

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                // ... your columns
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                // ---> Disable this if you want to hide Edit button
                // Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ]);
    }
    // ... the rest of your code
```